# How to create tests for kana (katakana/hiragana) using selenoid?

Tags: selenium, testing, selenoid, kana

We want to write e2e tests for the Katakana method using Selenoid. But how we can realize it?
There is should be exactly Latin input that converts into Katakana/Hiragana symbols.
Is there anybody here who has ideas or experiences about it?

Comment: At least browser images for Selenoid contain respective Japanese fonts and encodings.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't support for katakana input indeed. It has to be some system setting, something relates to the container, but I can't find the right decision